# How to output html files from pug templates with webpack?

Tags: webpack, webpack-html-loader, pug-loader

I'm trying to output individual html files from pug templates in my webpack project. The problem I'm having is in getting `pug-loader` to render html into the files.

My webpack.config:

```
const path = require('path');
const glob = require('glob');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const src = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');
const dist = path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist');

module.exports = {
  context: src,

  entry: {
    pug: glob.sync('./**/*.pug', {
      cwd: src
    }),
    index: path.resolve(src, 'index.js')
  },

  output: {
    path: dist,
    filename: '[name].js'
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['es2015'].map(dep =>
              require.resolve(`babel-preset-${dep}`)
            ) // Fix for lerna symlinked deps
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.pug$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[path][name].html'
            }
          },
          'extract-loader',
          'html-loader',
          'apply-loader',
          'pug-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

This correctly generates files for each pug template in my project, but the files do not contain html. Rather, each file looks something like:

```
var req = require("!!<absolute-path-to-project>/node_modules/pug-loader/index.js!<absolute-path-to-pug-file>/index.pug");
module.exports = (req['default'] || req).apply(req, [])
```

My installed dependency versions:

```
{
  "apply-loader": "^2.0.0",
  "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
  "babel-loader": "^7.1.0",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
  "extract-loader": "^0.1.0",
  "file-loader": "^0.11.1",
  "glob": "^7.1.2",
  "html-loader": "^0.4.5",
  "pug-loader": "^2.3.0",
  "webpack": "^3.0.0"
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Try to use pug-html-loader instead of pug-loader.

Here an example:

```
{
    test: /\.pug$/,
    use: [
      "file-loader?name=[path][name].html",
      "extract-loader",
      "html-loader",
      "pug-html-loader"
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

this question is old, but you needing delete "'html-loader'" of rules for working