# Build `html/index.pug` into `dist/index.html` using Webpack 5

Tags: javascript, webpack, pug, webpack-5, pug-loader

I'd like to build `html/index.pug` into `dist/index.html` using Webpack 5.

With Webpack 4 I used to use `file-loader` for this, but it seems deprecated in Webpack 5: no mentions of it in the [Loaders](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/) page. The Webpack 5 solutions seems to be using [Asset Modules](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/): that page makes it clear that `file-loader` was the old solution, for Webpack 4.

So far I failed to get it to work though. These are a couple of configurations I tried in my `webpack.config.js`'s `module.rules`:

###### 1. Using the `pug-loader` only

```
{
    test:path.resolve('./html/index.pug'),
    type:'asset/resource',
    loader:'pug-loader',
    generator:{filename:'index.html'}}
}
```

This creates a `dist/index.html` file which contains the following:

```
var pug = require("!../node_modules/pug-runtime/index.js");

function template(locals) {var pug_html = "", pug_mixins = {}, pug_interp;pug_html = pug_html + "\u003C!DOCTYPE html\u003E\u003Chtml lang=\"en\"\u003E\u003Chead\u003E\u003Ctitle\u003E" + (pug.escape(null == (pug_interp = "Hello World") ? "" : pug_interp)) + "\u003C\u002Ftitle\u003E\u003C\u002Fhead\u003E\u003Cbody\u003E\u003Cp\u003EHello World\u003C\u002Fp\u003E\u003C\u002Fbody\u003E\u003C\u002Fhtml\u003E";;return pug_html;};
module.exports = template;
```

It looks like `pug-loader` converts the pug file into a JavaScript module which generates the html code when it's called. What I want is the resulting HTML code, instead of a JS function that generates it.

###### 2. Using `val-loader` to execute the JavaScript module generated above

```
{
    test:path.resolve('./html/index.pug'),
    type:'asset/resource',
    use:['val-loader','pug-loader'],
    generator:{filename:'index.html'}}
}
```

This doesn't work either: Webpack throws an error when it tries to build `dist/index.pug`:

```
ERROR in ./html/index.pug
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/val-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: Unable to execute "/home/bluenebula/work/webpack5-test/html/index.pug": Error: Cannot find module '!../node_modules/pug-runtime/index.js'
```

Note that `/home/bluenebula/work/webpack5-test/node_modules/pug-runtime/index.js` does exist.

#### Question

1. Are Asset Modules the right tool to generate an HTML file from a Pug one using Webpack 5?
2. What else am I supposed to do?
3. How do I get it to work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to output html files from pug templates with webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44792582/how-to-output-html-files-from-pug-templates-with-webpack)

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky no, those answers are for Webpack 4 and use `file-loader`, `html-loader` etc. Those loaders were used in Webpack 4, but Webpack 5 introduces a new solution (Asset Modules) which is what I'm trying to use, failing: https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/

Answer (score 1):

(Pug 3.0.2) 
I replaced the loader '[pug-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pug-loader)' with '[@webdiscus/pug-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@webdiscus/pug-loader)',
and it works.

```
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(__dirname, 'src/index.pug'),
      filename: 'index.html',
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.pug$/,
        loader: '@webdiscus/pug-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
```

The reference I followed :
https://github.com/webdiscus/pug-loader#usage-in-javascript